# Camera Error 100 on .takePicture ONLY AFTER stopping a video recording

Tags: android, video, camera, photo, recording

Greetings StackOverflowers!

I've searched at great length, but finally have to admit I'm out of ideas.

Please find a minimalist Eclipse project at https://github.com/ppinter1/AndroidCamera.git which demonstrates the problem I'm having on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Android 4.1.1

In essence: the dreaded Camera Error 100 (with attendant death of ICamera/media server/Camera server) occurs whenever I call .takePicture after stopping a video recording.

What's tested and working in the code provided:

- any number of photos can be captured
- any number of videos can be recorded as well
- even taking a photo while recording works fine (a nice side effect)

BUT, taking a photo *after stopping a recording* (that is, either by hitting the 'Stop Recording' button, or because the recording is automatically stopped when the maximum file size of 5MB is reached) causes the generic Camera Error 100.

I would be most appreciative if others would test this code on their Android device.

Is it a bug just with this tablet? If it fails on other devices as well, can anyone tell me
what I'm doing wrong or how to diagnose this further?

If the code works for you, please reply with your device model and Android version.

With many thanks,

Pete

UPDATE:

Couple things:

- A Samsung Developer support tech reports no error running my github test code on an S3 device, but sees an Exception with Galaxy Tab and Nexus. He believes the test code uses the Camera API incorrectly, yet I don't think I can make the code any simpler... if anyone spots an API usage error, please correct me!
- I've opened an issue at [Google's Android tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52734) with additional log file detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed on the tracker link above, it turns out one needs to **Add an extra .stopPreview() after .reconnect() and before .startPreview**.

Massive thanks go to developer *etalv* on the Android Open Handset Alliance Project for the tip.